# Problems with measuring time in Javascript with new Date()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Hello I'm a beginner in Javascript programming.

I want to build a simple game with jquery, where you have to drag an drop the correct pics as fast as possible.
The problem now ist the time measurement. I wanted to measure the duration between pressing start and the end of the game (e.g correct cards = 10). I made two variables (startTime and endTime) which I wanted to use at the end of the code to subtract them to get the duration. But I can't use them.

What am I doing wrong? I thought it would be enough if i would make the variables global at the beginning.

This is the important part of my code:

```js
var startTime;
var endTime;


function handleCardDrop(event, ui) {
 var slotNumber = $(this).data('number');
 var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data('number');

 
 if (slotNumber == cardNumber) {
  ui.draggable.addClass('correct');
  ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
  $(this).droppable('disable');
  ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this),
   my: 'left top',
   at: 'left top'
  });
  ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
  correctCards++;
 }


 if (correctCards == 10) {
  var endTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log(endTime);
  console.log('Spiel endet');
 }


 // Only show slot, if the previous one is correct
 for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (correctCards == i) {
   $('#slot' + [i + 1]).css('display', 'block')
  }
 }
}

$('#startButton').click(function Ball() {
 var startTime = new Date().getTime();
 console.log(startTime);
 console.log('Spiel beginnt');
 $('#ball').animate({
  left: '+=800'
 }, 20000, "linear");

});


function time() {
  var timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
  timeDiff /= 1000;
  var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff);
  console.log(seconds + " seconds");
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="content">
    <button id="startButton">Start</button>
    <div id="cardPile"> </div>
    <div id="ball"></div>
    <div id="cardSlots"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: ?? What exactly is the problem? How does that `time()` function get called?  Also note that JavaScript timestamp values are in *milliseconds*, not seconds.

Comment: Your `startTime` and `endTime` are scoped to their respective functions, where they were declared in. They are not visible inside the function `time`. This is because you use `var` again - you shadow the global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redeclaring the variables `endTime` and `startTime` inside their respective functions, which is creating new local-scoped variables. Remove the `var` declaration and you will be able to access the values of the global variables. You should also call your `time` function when the game ends.

```
var startTime;
var endTime;


function handleCardDrop(event, ui) {
    var slotNumber = $(this).data('number');
    var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data('number');


    if (slotNumber == cardNumber) {
        ui.draggable.addClass('correct');
        ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
        $(this).droppable('disable');
        ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this),
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'left top'
        });
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
        correctCards++;
    }


    if (correctCards == 10) {
        endTime = new Date().getTime();
        time();
        console.log(endTime);
        console.log('Spiel endet');
    }


    // Only show slot, if the previous one is correct
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        if (correctCards == i) {
            $('#slot' + [i + 1]).css('display', 'block')
        }
    }
}

$('#startButton').click(function Ball() {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(startTime);
    console.log('Spiel beginnt');
    $('#ball').animate({
        left: '+=800'
    }, 20000, "linear");

});


function time() {
  var timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
  timeDiff /= 1000;
  var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff);
  console.log(seconds + " seconds");
}
```

Comment: correct , One more thing to add `time()` to your end logic  `if (correctCards == 10) {
        endTime = new Date().getTime();
        time();
        console.log(endTime);
        console.log('Spiel endet');
    }
`

Comment: @PranoySarkar Thanks for telling me. I have edited my answer.

Comment: No, it doesn't @PranoySarkar

Comment: @Nina , welcome, although it works its not a good idea to make global variables, dubugging will be lot harder when it will grow big.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually declaring multiple startTime and endTime variables in different [scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). To keep referencing the global variables, **declare** each of them once at the top of the file using `var` and then **reference** those global variables later on without `var`.

To calculate the difference, you should call your `time()` function when the game ends.

For more info, have a look at [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) and the [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keyword in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-declaring your 'startTime' and 'endTime.  Just remove the variable declaration from those two after your initial 'var' declaration in line 1 & 2 of your code snippet.